# How to get the postion of the mouse during Button OnClick

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void lbkShowWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

How do I get the position of the mouse when I click the `LinkButton`?

Comment: What framework(s) are you using? Have you searched and consulted its documentation?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517198/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-jquery-without-mouse-events) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. ASP.NET WebForm's events are an abstraction on top of the HTTP `<form>` POST action. Web browsers don't submit the coordinates of the cursor.

Long answer: it's possible, using a variety of means depending on your scenario. The "easiest" way is to use a framework like jQuery and handle client-side mouse-click events for every element on the page, when the mouse is clicked you intercept the form's `onsubmit` action and update an `<input type="hidden" />` with the coordinates and then let the form submission continue.

...or use an `<input type="image" />` which includes the coordinates when submitted http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.image.html

Of course, your code makes an assumption that the user is using a mouse to begin with. There are other web user-agents that don't have pointing devices, like smartphones, touch-tablets, and spiders.

Comment: thank u dude~i us jquery to save the value in hid~an i get the value with c# code~

Answer (score 1):

Capture the mouse position from client side (as mentioned in the previous answer) at the **mousemove** event and keep in a hidden field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
        var currentPos = "X:" + event.pageX;
        currentPos += ",Y:" + event.pageY;
        $("#hdMousePosition").val(currentPos);
    });            
});
```