# Call javascript mouse event with event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, mouse

So I want to be able to trigger my mousemove function in jquery using $().mousemove(), but I want to also be able to pass the current mouse state as a parameter, so my mousemove function knows the mouse x and y coordinates.

I understand that a possible workaround is just to save the x and y coordinates and create a function that directly uses these coordinates, but I wanted to know if there was a way to just get the current mouse event.

Example:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    // do stuff with x and y
});

function trigger_mousemove() {
    $(document).mousemove(/** here is where I want something to be able to put in */);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure to give your whole code access to a variable that is updated by a mousemove handler:

```
var mouseX, mouseY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
}).mouseover(); // call the handler immediately

// do something with mouseX and mouseY
```

cytation from user lonesomeday if you like the answer give him credit in link below.
See [How to get mouse position in jQuery without mouse-events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517198/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-jquery-without-mouse-events) for reference

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be way to actually get the object, but I guess there isn't. Thanks a bunch