# Need to make an element face my cursor, for a game project.(Using canvas is not an option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to find help with setting up some code to make an element box's bottom side always face the cursor. I am building a simple 3 stage top down shooter as part of a small portfolio project. My partner has us using Hype 3 and so I cannot take advantage of the HTML Canvas.

Is there a way to do this using plain javascript or jquery?

Comment: add some sample images.

Comment: I don't really have the time to finish it - but I got you started: https://jsfiddle.net/bLtk10uu/1/

Comment: I had to try this myself: https://jsfiddle.net/bLtk10uu/2/

Comment: Hey kalsowerus, there a way to make this work with an Id instead of class? I tried making some changes to get it to work with an id instead and it breaks the function to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check [mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517198/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-jquery-without-mouse-events), then check your block position, and do some simple trigonometry to calculate angle.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it gave me a great place to start and figure out the rest!